# Angular Material Progress Bar - Reworked to a moving div with text

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

I need to create this with Angular Material2.

[image]

As the 'Expected Progress' & 'Your Progress' will be a percentage I thought that I could create 3 stacked progress bars but heavily style the top and bottom one so that in the place of the bar there is a div containing the text with a down/up caret in the middle below/above that moves along the horizontal axis to the point set by the percentage value. I don't know if it is possible and don't want to embark on hours of messing with the bar styles only to find it won't work. I know for SO I need to supply attempted code but I don't even know where to start. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about using CSS Grid to create your layout?

### CSS Grid Layout

- CSS Tricks: [A Complete Guide to CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- Grid By Example: [CSS Grid Layout by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/learn/)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure that would work as I need to move the 'Expected Progress' & 'Your Progress'  elements along the horizontal axis based on a percentage value. That is why I thought progress bars would be the way forward.